# FILE NOT FOUND error in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This code gives me a `file not found` error and I don't know if it is the file location that is giving me troubles. I'm new to Python.

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt')

#file location = 'C:\Users\qeee11\Downloads\breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt'
```

df

Comment: Does your current working directory point to `"C:\Users\qeee11\Downloads"`? If not, you need to put full path.

Comment: This is the current directory

Comment: To make sure, you are in the correct working directory, i. e. the folder, where your file is located, you could either use the the full path, as @VivekKumar suggested or type 
`import os`
`os.chdir('C:\Users\qeee11\Downloads\')`

To test, if your file is really there, try:
`print(os.listdir('.'))`

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Don't forget to put `r` in front of the windows paths like `r"C:\Users\qeee11\Downloads\"`

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd. read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt') 
# Give commands to extract the directory like getcwd()
#like , data_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')

file location = 'C:\Users\qeee11\Downloads\breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt'
```

[getcwd() details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm)

Another solution is to use `!` shell commands , to change the directory,
you can write commands like `!cd` , and `!ls` to change the directory to the current file.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Your answer is highly confusing: As a start: The first two lines are the exact same ones that OP has posted and will give therefor the same error. Your comment doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. How does `data_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')` fit in here?

Comment: The first 2 lines will not give an error , if the directory gets changed.
There are 2 ways of changing it , using the python function getcwd() , and using shell operations using pre-exclamation to denote that it is a shell command.
I was trying to illustrated these 2 ways of solving the issue of file path.

Comment: All this is unnecessary. He just needs to give the full path.

Comment: @abunickabhi How about you clearly state that in your answer. Also. `getcwd` does not change the directory (Note how the name contains `get`)

Comment: `getcwd` can be used to access the string that denotes where the file is stored in , and then the command  `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')` will do the trick.

Comment: just no, this is so wrong, if the file is in the current working directory, then doing `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), <filename>)` would generate a full path to the file. But in no way would it change the current working directory and it would also not magically "access the string that denotes where the file is stored in". And if the file was already in the curent working directory, then there would be no issue in the first place

Comment: Correct , the getcwd() apporach is a hassle , if we just take care and open the file in the current directory.